# values are not getting populated in yaml file of helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Learning to create helm chart.

My `values.yaml`:

```
image:
  repository: myimage
  tag: latest
```

Inside my deployment.yaml, I am trying to do `image: {{ (.Values.image).repository }}:{{ (.Values.image).tag }}`, which gives the following error: `mapping values are not allowed in this context`.

`image: {{ (.Values.image).repository }}:latest` does not print the `repository` value from the values.yaml. No errors given. (testing using helm template demochart).

Right now, I do not have `_helpers.tpl`. Is that file necessary? My current file structure:

```
demochart
|-- Chart.yaml
|-- templates
|   `-- deployment.yaml
`-- values.yaml
```

If I do `image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}:latest`, this gives `at <.Values.image.repository>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.repository`.

What I am doing wrong?

Do I need to include `values.yaml` somewhere? if yes, how?

Comment: That syntax should work, though the parentheses should be unnecessary and the combination of error messages is a little odd.  To confirm, that `image:` line is in the `templates/deployment.yaml` file, and it's not inside a `range`, `with`, or `define` block?  The `image:` settings are at the top level in `values.yaml`?

Comment: @DavidMaze, yes, it is at the top level. I just copy pasted whole `values.yaml`.